# Errors/warnings being reported by three.js for non-working CubeCamera example

Tags: javascript, three.js, runtime-error, textures

I have a very simple CubeCamera/reflection example (lifted largeley from Stemkoski's reflection example).  Code looks like this:

```
var sphereGeom =  new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2, 32, 32 ); 
mirrorSphereCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 0.1, 5000, 512 );
scene.add( mirrorSphereCamera );

var mirrorSphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { envMap: mirrorSphereCamera.renderTarget } );    
mirrorSphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeom, mirrorSphereMaterial );
mirrorSphere.position.set(0, 2, 0);
mirrorSphereCamera.position = mirrorSphere.position;
scene.add(mirrorSphere)
```

The render code looks like this

```
mirrorSphere.visible = false;
mirrorSphereCamera.updateCubeMap( renderer, scene );
mirrorSphere.visible = true;
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

With three.js 60 it works fine though I get these warnings:

```
[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x7f80b4013200]RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0
[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x7f80b4013200]RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0
[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x7f80b4013200]RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0
```

Wth three.js 75 I get this error:

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: bindTexture: textures can not be used with multiple targets
```

And with the latest build 82, I get these warnings:

```
THREE.WebGLPrograms.getTextureEncodingFromMap: don't use render targets as textures. Use their .texture property instead.
THREE.WebGLRenderer.setTextureCube: don't use cube render targets as textures. Use their .texture property instead.
```

In neither 75 nor 82 does the reflection work. And despite the warning from 82, [the example at threejs.org](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderTargetCube) still uses the renderTarget (AFAICT):

I'm still investigating, but any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I have added a jsFiddle for this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/richardylewright/ejuofnye/14/)

Comment: I have verified that the fiddle referenced above worked until release 68 (r68).  Up through r67 it worked with the  code:                                         var mirrorSphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { envMap: mirrorSphereCamera.renderTarget } );      After that it doesn't work either with that syntax or using the .texture member of renderTarget.

Comment: The answer is that as of r68, the Vector3 objects became immutable and had to be assigned explicitly or copied. So the correct code is mirrorSphere.position.set(0, 2, 0); mirrorSphereCamera.position.copy(mirrorSphere.position); I have updated the fiddle accordingly.